# what should i do so the user can enter their own data

Tags: c++

Create a c++ program which accepts an employee’s full name,
hours worked, and pay grade, and displays the employee’s
name, and salary. The following data should be stored in parallel arrays.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)

{
    string firstnamearr[10] = {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "};
    string lastnamearr[10] = {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "};
    int paygrade[10] = {};
    int hoursworked[10] = {};
    int salary[10] = {};

    cout << "\n The Names,Paygrade,Hoursworked and Salary of employees:";
    cout << "\n -------------------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n firstname\tlastname\tpaygrade\thoursworked\tsalary";
    cout << "\n ----------------------------------------------------------";

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n  " << firstnamearr[i] <<"\t\t" << lastnamearr[i] << "\t\t" << paygrade[i]
             << "\t\t" << hoursworked[i] << "\t\t" << salary[i];
    }
    cout << "\n --------------------------------------------------"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A question title should be about the specific problem you are facing, not about your state of mind.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: Do you know about `std::cin`? Any [beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have told you about it.

Comment: Also instead of using 5 separate arrays, it would be better so use a `struct Employee` containing 5 single member variables and use an array of such structs.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont have to fill the arrays just use:

```
string firstNameArr[10] = {};
```

etc.

Then just use:

```
cin >> firstNameArr[0];
```

etc.

But I would recommend a `std::vector` as @tobi303 already said its just an Array with dynamic size!

Comment: using a list is overkill if he doesnt need to add/remove elements in the middle of the container

Comment: Yeah you are propably right i never used lists in c++ i thought maybe it would be better... I'm new too :D

Comment: you could recommend him a `std::vector` which is basically just an array with dynamic size